# Forecasting discrete non normal data

Tags: prediction, count-data, skewness

Today I was thinking about how one would treat what I'm guessing must come up constantly in statistics so apologies if it's trivial.

Some statistics such are easy to forecast, such as length, thanks to their normalish properties. But what if I'm interested in forecasting something like the number of children someone will birth? This seems to be a rather weird case to me. It's not only skewed, but it also has a lower bound of zero. Also, even if we're disregarding the time of pregnancy, the probability of birthing a child in a given year isn't independent, i.e. $P(X>0) \neq P(X>1|X>0)$, so it shouldn't be Poisson either.

How would one treat a phenomenon like this?

Comment: Since the normal is continuous, specifying 'discrete' already means it can't be normal. It is *not* a general property of the Poisson that $P(X>0) = P(X>1|X>0)$ (you may be partially confusing it with the geometric?)

Comment: The distribution of numbers of births to a woman is very different in South Korea and in Niger - not just the average but also the distributional shape differs. It's unlikely that any country has a distribution of births that matches closely any particular named distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b I only meant that the probability of having a kid in a given year is dependant on if you already have a kid. A poisson process needs to have independent probabilities, no?

Comment: You seem to be confusing conditions for a Poisson process with the a distribution observed at some time. While a Poisson process with constant rate will produce a Poisson distribution, a different process, or mixture of different processes might also do it. Further, the independence of events in a Poisson process is not the same as $P(X>0) = P(X>1|X>0)$. They're talking about different things.

Comment: You might find this information helpful: http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/gnxp/2012/08/what-is-the-distribution-of-offspring-per-individual/  (distributional information for the US)

Comment: To clarify: I agree that births over time *for one individual* don't follow a Poisson process. That doesn't *imply* that the total births for some person aren't Poisson - that doesn't automatically follow. However, total births won't be Poisson in any case, just because they won't be any named distribution in particular. Poisson might be a reasonable approximation in some cases, but probably not in others.

Comment: So you're basically saying there's no general solutions to these types of distributions?

Comment: "*solution*" may not be the word you're seeking. There's no equation here to solve. Real processes tend not to have named distributions, except as approximations. There are many discrete distributions that serve as useful approximations

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at a specific country; [data for the USA](https://www.census.gov/hhes/fertility/data/cps/2010.html)

For all women, 15 to 44:

```
47.1% had 0 kids
16.9% had 1
20.4% had 2
10.4% had 3
3.4% had 4
1.5% had 5 or 6 
0.3% had 7 or more.
```

which averages (making a couple assumptions) to $1.13$ kids per woman.

A Poisson with $\lambda = 1.13$ gives:

```
0 = 32%
1 = 37%
2 = 21%
3 = 7.5%
4 = 2.1%
5 = 0.4%
more = 0.1%
```

so, at least for the USA, it's not Poisson. Perhaps a zero inflated negative binomial would work.